# Record Line in with auto-splitting

Tags: mp3, audio-recording, windows-server-2003

I have a server that serves as a streaming server. It's a Dell PowerEdge 2650 that gets the audio via Line In and uses EDCast to send it off to an Icecast2 server in a datacenter.

Everything is working very well but I'm trying to find a program that will allow me te record the Line In and allows me to split the MP3's in 30-min-parts (dealbreaker otherwise).

I'm aware of Audacity but it seems to lack this feature. A free solution would be great but not really necessary.

OS: Windows Server 2003

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it.

First, download HardiskOgg and configure a good preset. Then call this in a bat/startup-script.

```
Harddisk.exe -record -preset "C:\Radio\OK.hdp" -output "C:\Radio\Radio001.mp3" -sequential -timeslice 1800
```